# How to build a binary from multiple c++ files?

Tags: c++

I have started learning C++, and have gotten stuck when working with multiple files. To practice basic classes, I wrote three different files,

- working.cpp
- word.cpp
- word.h

---

**word.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "word.h"
using namespace std;
class word{

public:
char *word;

void createWord(char *str)
{
    word = str;
}

void print_word(void)
{
    cout<<word<<endl;
}

char * getWord()
{
    return word;
}
```

}

**working.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "word.h"
void printWord(word);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
word one;
one.createWord("one");

printWord(one);

}

void printWord(word a)
{
cout<<a.getWord()<<endl;
}
```

**word.h**

```
class word;
```

---

These are three different files, so I am not sure how to compile them. What I have tried is
`g++ working.cpp word.cpp`

However, the compiler doesn't recognize word as a class, and gives me the following errors

```
working.cpp: In function 'int main()':
working.cpp:7:7: error: aggregate 'word one' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
working.cpp:7:12: error: aggregate 'word two' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
working.cpp:7:17: error: aggregate 'word three' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
working.cpp: In function 'void printWord(word)':
working.cpp:19:6: error: 'aha' has incomplete type
In file included from working.cpp:2:0:
word.h:2:7: error: forward declaration of 'class word'
word.cpp:25:1: error: expected ';' after class definition
```

What am I doing wrong while compiling?

Comment: Start with a good book, there are many issues with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to include more of the definition of `word` in the header file.  Something like this:

   ```
   class word
   {
   public:
       char *word;
       void createWord(char *str);
       void print_word(void);
       char * getWord();
   };
   ```
2. Then, change `word.cpp` to just have the implementations:

   ```
   void word::createWord(char *str)
   {
       word = str;
   }

   void word::print_word(void)
   {
       cout<<word<<endl;
   }

   char * word::getWord()
   {
       return word;
   }
   ```
3. compile and link!

You need to have more of the `word` class in the header so that your other translation unit can know how big the class is (to reserve enough space for the instance you're creating) as well as to know the names of the methods you want to call.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it worked. I am a little used to how classes are defined in more high-level languages so it got me confused while writing classes.

Answer (score 3):

Just mentioning the class name in the header file (a so-called *forward declaration*) is not enough; you need a complete class declaration (which declares all the fields and functions of the class):

```
class word {
public:
    char *word;
    void createWord(char *str);
    void print_word(void);
    char * getWord();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual declaration of class `word` in `word.h`

```
word.h:2:7: error: forward declaration of 'class word'
```

I would advise you to read Bjarne Stroustrup's brilliant book "The C++ Programming Language" to get started.